# GitHub creating a new branch and pushing to it

Tags: git, github

How do I create a new branch in Git hub called "stage 1" and then push my work up to that branch without saving over or harming what is in the master branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branch name cannot contains space char.

Create a new branch,

```
git checkout -b stage-1
```

Develop anything. After that `commit` and `push`.

```
git commit -am . "commit message"
git push orgin stage-1
```

Answer (score 0):

This page explains how to create a branch.
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository/

Branch is just a copy of the master branch. So it won't harm anything in the master branch.